# Not displaying the error messages in PHP

Tags: php

If there are any errors while registration or login into the sit then it is not displaying the error message just printing the variable.Here is the code.Tried by doing echo as well but it is also not working.Tried with storing the result in a variable and displaying the message but still not worked.

```
    <?php 
include 'includes/db.php';
$match = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit_user']))
{
     $email = $_POST['email'];
      $check=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where user_email='$email'");
      $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);
      if($checkrows>0) 
      {           
          $msg = "Email Already Exists";
          header('Location:registration.php?msg=$msg');
      } 
      else 
      {
        if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['con_password'])
        {
            $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, user_email, user_password, username) VALUES ('$_POST[first_name]', '$_POST[last_name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[username]')";
            $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql);
        }
        else 
        {
            $match = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Password doesn&apos;t match!</div>';
        }
      }

} 

        ?>
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="registration.php" method="post" role="form">
                <div class="body">
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" id="first_name" onkeypress="return checkSpcialChar(event)" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                                   
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" name="email"  id="email" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"  id="password" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="type" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="con_password"  id="con_password" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                            
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username"  id="username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group drop-custum">
                                <select class="form-control show-tick" name="user_role" id="user_role" required>
                                    <option value="">-- Select User role --</option>
                                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                    <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised g-bg-cyan" name="submit_user" id="subject">Submit</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        <span>
                         <?php if(isset($_GET['msg']))
                          echo $_GET['msg'];
                          ?>
                        </span>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: (1) Your code is wide open to SQL injection, which is not only a gaping security flaw but also a common source of bugs and problems.  (2) You're storing user passwords in plain text, which is *grossly irresponsible* to your users.  (3) What specifically is the problem you're facing?  The description is unclear.

Comment: Did you getting any error?

Comment: Is this script called `registration.php`

Comment: @David if their is any duplicate in email i want to show the error message as Email Already exists

Comment: `$variables` are not expanded in a single quoted string literal `header('Location:registration.php?msg=$msg');` so use a double quoted string literal`header("Location:registration.php?msg=$msg");`

Comment: @RameshKumar not getting any error at the bottom it is displaying as $msg

Comment: It is also a good idea to put an `exit;` after a `header("Location: ...)` as the `header()` function does not stop execution like you may be thinking

Comment: You also dont seem to output `$match` anywhere if that is the message you are looking for but not getting

Comment: use header("Location:registration.php?msg=$msg");

Comment: @RiggsFolly tank you its working fine now

Comment: @RiggsFolly just one clarificatiion if i dont want to show the message in URL then what should i do

Comment: Store the error in the session. If error exists in session show it, then delete it so it does not show again

Comment: @RiggsFolly not getting you what you are saying

Comment: Have you used the PHP session before?

Comment: yes i have used